# Can you help me for creating table with unix timetamp?

Tags: mysql, database, database-administration

i was try these stps

```
(SET @tablename = unix_timestamp();

CREATE TABLE @tablename like Existing_table;


UNIX_TIMESTAMP()

SET @SQL = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ', DATE_FORMAT(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'%Y_%m_%d'), '_new_table LIKE Existing_table');
PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;)
?
```

Comment: DATE_FORMAT(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'%Y_%m_%d') returns null so @sql is null -why not format current_date or now()?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert unix_timestamp to a date before formatting https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

```
select DATE_FORMAT(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()),'%Y_%m_%d');

+---------------------------------------------------------+
| DATE_FORMAT(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()),'%Y_%m_%d') |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| 2022_10_07                                              |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)

SET @SQL = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ', DATE_FORMAT(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()),'%Y_%m_%d'), '_new_table LIKE Existing_table');

select @sql;

+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @sql                                                                |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 2022_10_07_new_table LIKE Existing_table |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```